# adding effect to knockout "if" binding

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I've found examples in the knockout.js documentation on how to add a jquery effect when toggling the visible binding or even using the beforeRemove event of the 'foreach' binding.

However, I have not found out how to add a jquery effect when toggling the "if" binding

Consider the following code:

```
<table data-bind="with: myModel">
 <tr data-bind="if: IsVisible">
<td>some string</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

How would I add a jquery fadeIn effect when IsVisible returns true ?

Comment: Best: **don't**. `if` alters the DOM. Create a new binding, as shown in the [fade binding example](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/animatedTransitions.html).

Comment: thanks but i'm not sure I understand your reply. I want to use the if binding, as I indeed need to alter the DOM. Should I create a custom binding to embed the if binding and add some jquery logic there ?

Comment: The `if` binding does magic with creating/removing elements (the one it is bound to and everything under it). *This makes `if` very problematic to try and use with a transition* - the element either doesn't exist yet or has already been removed. It is possible to "hack" about it, but it's a very ugly cludge and I'm not even sure it will work reliably everywhere. Unless it is a requirement that the DOM is *altered*, simply use a custom binding that applies an affect without otherwise altering the DOM.

Comment: Good point about the hooks with `foreach` binding - I don't believe there is similar for `if`, however.

Comment: ok, good point. I'll try the custom binding and let you know !

Comment: I provided an answer using a custom binding. If it works for you, please mark it accepted.

Comment: Michael's answer should be marked as accepted.

Comment: True, and I've just done so :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use the `if` binding directly, but using a custom binding within the `if` binding would do the trick:

```
<table data-bind="with: myModel">
    <tr data-bind="if: IsVisible">
        <!--ko fadeIn: true-->
        <td>some string</td>
        <!--/ko-->
    </tr>
</table>
```

Handler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.fadeIn = {
    init: function(element) {
        $(ko.virtualElements.childNodes(element))
            .filter(function () { return this.nodeType == 1; })
            .hide()
            .fadeIn();
    }
};
ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings.fadeIn = true;
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/fpnTH/

Comment: Fantastic answer - worked great.  Much appreciated! :D